# Use compressed gzip file with UploadBlobAsync method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to compress a json string and save it als gzip file. I have the following code below which works but only saving it as a .json file. Using compression the files are smaller. If I compress the json string and change the filename to .gz I cannot open it using 7zip.

```
        string containerEndpoint = string.Format("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/datafolder");
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(containerEndpoint), null);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        string fileName = "test.gz";
        string blobPath = string.Format("folder/{0}", fileName);

        await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobPath, stream);
```

Comment: you can use GZipStream with your MemoryStream to generate the outStream before UploadBlobAsync

Comment: Where are you compressing the content before uploading? Simply changing the file extension to `gz` will not compress the content.

Comment: Unrelated: Mind that you lose unicode compatibility using the ASCII encoding here. (May not be relevant, just saying) You should also dispose of the MemoryStream gracefully ("using").

Answer (score 1):

I added your suggestions and it worked. My code is now as follows:

```
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            var compressedData = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

            var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
            stream.Position = 0;
            string blobPath = string.Format("folder/{0}", fileName);
            await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobPath, stream);

        }
```

Comment: If you want the browsers to automatically decompress the `gz` files, please make sure that you set the `Content-Encoding` property of the blob to be `gzip`. HTH.

Comment: Anyone using this as reference, the `blockCopy` related lines have no purpose w.r.to upload your gzipped stream to blob storage.